# Unable to clone repository with Git

Tags: windows-7, git, clone

I am trying to clone a repository on my machine that I have just created on GitHub.

I am new to Git, but have been using SVN for a while. I've set up an RSA key as per instructions but am unable to clone with either the SSH or HTTP Urls.

When I use HTTP, I get the following error:

```
Password: fatal: Out of memory, realloc failed
```

I'm using Windows 7 with MSysGit (using Bash & PuTTY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Git in Cygwin. For me Git works better in Cygwin than as MSysGit.